# Mac OS X Native Menu - How to destroy and access via dockSupport.dockMenu

Tags: macos, firefox-addon

I create and add an item to Mac OS X native menu. I add the menu to a window.

If I modify the menu item in this window it also changes it in the native menu. So if I do `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').myMacMenuItem.setAttribute('label','CHANGED')` it will change the label the DOM of that window and consequently change the DOM in the Mac native menu.

However after this window closes I can't access the dom element anymore but the item persists in the dock. Is it possible to get the dom and modify by doing like: `dockSupport.dockMenu.SOMETHING`.

So I was wondering:
1. How to access the DOM of the menu via `dockSupport.dockMenu.SOMETHING.childNodes[0].label = 'CHANGED'`;
2. How to destroy this, there is a `dockSupport.dockMenu.init` but no `uninit`

```
var dockSupport = Cc['@mozilla.org/widget/macdocksupport;1'].getService(Ci.nsIMacDockSupport);
console.log('dockSupport:', dockSupport);

var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var macMenu = win.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'menupopup');
macMenu.setAttribute('id', 'myMacMenu');
var macMenuItem = win.document.createElementNS('http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul', 'menuitem');
macMenuItem.setAttribute('label', 'Show Most Recent Window');
macMenuItem.setAttribute('id', 'myMacMenuItem');
macMenuItem.addEventListener('command', function(){
  var dockSupport = Cc['@mozilla.org/widget/macdocksupport;1'].getService(Ci.nsIMacDockSupport);
  dockSupport.activateApplication(true);
  Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null).focus()
})
macMenu.appendChild(macMenuItem);
var mainPopupSet = win.document.getElementById('mainPopupSet');
mainPopupSet.appendChild(macMenu);

let dockMenuElement = macMenu; //document.getElementById("menu_mac_dockmenu");66
let nativeMenu = Cc["@mozilla.org/widget/standalonenativemenu;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStandaloneNativeMenu);

console.log('dockMenuElement:', dockMenuElement);

nativeMenu.init(dockMenuElement);
dockSupport.dockMenu = nativeMenu;
```

it looks like this:

[image: adds item to mac os x native menu]

Comment: The main reason I ask this is because I want to access `dockSupport.dockMenu` to see if other items are already existing, and then just add mine, not overwrite the old ones.

Comment: Most any of this type of stuff (including your other question about simulating a button press) is all handled by the Accessibility classes: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/Accessibility_RoleAttribute_Ref/Actions.html